# I am planning to use the noise texture to make the cylinders go up and down how can I achieve this?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

this image is the current node system I made. If it is a mess I was just toying around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Geometry is still an instance, use the Translate Instances node.

[image]

Depending on what kind of motion you are going for, animate one of the axes of a noise texture. In my case, I will animate the W axis of a 4D noise texture.

[image]

Comment: Oh right! I forgot that another word for transform is translate. Thanks

Comment: @user15303824 Actually translation is just one kind of a transformation. While transformations can be translating, rotating, scaling etc. a translation is just translating, the shifting of a location. Sorry for being pedantic  ;)

Comment: no no, thanks for mentioning to me the meaning behind both and now I know. Thank you